# Keep getting WIN32Exception when running FFMPEG in ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, video, ffmpeg

I have an ASP.NET project and I want to use FFMPEG to help create thumbails for my videos.  I've loaded FFMPEG into the project, and whenever I run my code I get the same error:

'ffmpeg.MainModule' threw an exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
{"A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process."}

I'm using VS 2013, and I've set my target platform to x86, and made 100% sure I am using the 32bit version of ffmpeg.  I'm using the static libraries from this site (http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)  I also tried to change the target platform to All CPUs or x64, and tried with both 32 and 64 bit versions of FFMPEG.  Always the same error.  I am running IIS Express when I test in my local environment.

Here is my code.  Would appreciate any help!

```
String vSource = "http://example.com/myvideo.mp4";
String path1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;

Process ffmpeg = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/exe/ffmpeg.exe"), "-i " + vSource + "-ss 00:00:05.000 -f image2 -vframes 1 " + path1 +"thumbnail1.jpg");

startinfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startinfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ffmpeg.StartInfo = startinfo;

ffmpeg.Start();
```

Comment: did you checked the Trust Level ?

Answer (score 0):

Lance,

My guest is that IIS Express is running in 64bit mode regardless of the configuration in your project. I'd try to run it on IIS (not express) and set the application pool you're using to 32bit. The setting is called: Enable 32bit Applications (default: false). You can find it under the advanced settings of the application pool.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Bart, 

I've checked and I am running the 32bit version of IIS Express.  If I try to run the 64bit version of IIS I get an error saying "System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyProject'or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  And my website won't even start.  

Also in task manager I see it says "IIS Express Worker Process (32 bit)".

Comment: Lance, Have you tried it without setting the redirect properties?